# In Scala, why do I get this "polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type"?

Tags: scala

Why does the following occur in Scala 2.9.0.1?

```
scala> def f(xs: Seq[Either[Int,String]]) = 0
f: (xs: Seq[Either[Int,String]])Int

scala> val xs = List(Left(0), Right("a")).iterator.toArray
xs: Array[Product with Serializable with Either[Int,java.lang.String]] = Array(Left(0), Right(a))

scala> f(xs)
res39: Int = 0

scala> f(List(Left(0), Right("a")).iterator.toArray)
<console>:9: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [B >: Product with Serializable with Either[Int,java.lang.String]]Array[B]
 required: Seq[Either[Int,String]]
       f(List(Left(0), Right("a")).iterator.toArray)
                                            ^
```

**Update**: Debilski suggests a better example (not 100% sure this is demonstrating the same underlying phenomenon):

```
Seq(0).toArray : Seq[Int] // compiles
Seq(Some(0)).toArray : Seq[Option[Int]] // doesn't
```

Comment: You can also have the following minimal example `Seq(0).toArray : Seq[Int]` (compiles) vs `Seq(Some(0)).toArray : Seq[Option[Int]]` (does not compile).

Comment: Nice, thanks for the better example. Updating the question with it.

Comment: You can gain additional information by adding -Xlog-implicits to the startup command for Scala. It prints out some additional information on why it can't use the implicit conversion. The interesting question raised here, for me, is understanding why a val of an expression and an expression have different types.

Answer (score 6):

The best person to explain this is Adriaan Moors, and he already did that here on Stack Overflow -- lookup answers from him and you'll find it.

Anyway, the problem is that the type of `List(Left(0), Right("a")).iterator.toArray` cannot be inferred within the boundaries expected by `f`. It does not conform to `Seq[Either[Int, String]]` without an implicit conversion, and no implicit conversion can be applied because it (the type) cannot be determined. It's like an egg&chicken problem.

If you use `<%` or assign it to a val, you break the cycle in the inference.

Comment: Sure, but I'm still trying to figure out why the inference engine fails at this particular set of constraints, while, e.g., `def f(xs: Seq[Int]) = 0; f(List(0,1).toArray)` works (which also features an implicit conversion to `Seq[Int]`).

Comment: Another way to understand my confusion is to see my original alternative example with the two steps - the inference works in this case, from `xs: Array[...]` to `Seq[...]`. The return type of the `....toArray` expression is `Array[...]` as well, yet the inference breaks here.

Comment: My first comment here should say `f(List(0,1).iterator.toArray)` to be analogous to my original example.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `Either` but rather with `Array` handling. If you convert it manually to a `Seq` it works:

```
scala> f(xs.toSeq)
res4: Int = 0
```

A Scala `Array` is not a `Seq` (because it is in fact a Java array). But a `WappedArray` is. You could also redefine your function `f` has:

```
scala> def f[A <% Seq[Either[Int,String]]](xs: A) = 0
f: [A](xs: A)(implicit evidence$1: (A) => Seq[Either[Int,String]])Int

scala> f(xs)
res5: Int = 0
```

BTW, no need to get an iterator before calling `toArray`.

Comment: Because a `Seq` is a `Seq` ? Perhaps I am missing completely the point ?

Comment: Have a look at my other comment. What I mean is: it breaks with `Seq[Either[Int, String]]`, yet it works with `Seq[Int]`.

Comment: Yeah, something is still missing from this explanation. It has *something* to do with the Eithers, since if I'm just using List(0,1) I don't see this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because you cannot turn an Array into an Array, but you can convert a Sequence into an Array. The method wants a Sequence that it can use to make an Array.

Bottom line is to check the method signatures and not guess what they are based on the method name.

The important part is this:

```
found   : [B >: Product with Serializable with Either[Int,java.lang.String]]Array[B]
 required: Seq[Either[Int,String]]
       f(List(Left(0), Right("a")).iterator.toArray)
```

The `toArray` method wants a Seq (so a List would be fine) and it returns an Array. You have passed it an Array and it does not know what to do. Either make the Array into a Seq first, or just skip the `toArray` method entirely.

If you go back one step it is clear that the `iterator` method takes your List and returns an Array. Each method invocation is a function call.

Comment: Don't think it's quite that simple, since `def f(xs: Seq[Int]) = 0; f(List(0,1).toArray)` works.

Comment: Now you are adding List to the mix, but then List is just a subclass of Seq. It makes sense to convert a List to an Array, but it does not make sense to convert an Array to an Array.

Comment: I should have written `f(List(0,1).iterator.toArray)`, but it still works, so there's something more here.

Comment: Try just plain List(0,1).iterator and List(Left(0), Right("a")).iterator to see the difference. It looks like a Cartesian product has two dimensions and therefore is an Array instead of a List

Comment: Still lost. Your last comment is just my original example - `f(List(Left(0),Right("a")).iterator.toArray)` doesn't work, `f(List(0,1).iterator.toArray)` does, and I'm trying to understand why. I don't follow your explanation - how is `.iterator` returning an `Array` / how am I passing an array to `.toArray`?