# Interesting findings when combining Arrays in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm having some trouble understanding Array combination in Scala.

The following works fine:

```
scala> Array('0', '1', '2') ++ Array('A', 'B', 'C')
res0: Array[Char] = Array(0, 1, 2, A, B, C)
```

But this one does not:

```
scala> ('0' to '9').toArray ++ ('A' to 'Z').toArray
<console>:8: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [B >: Char]Array[B]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
              ('0' to '9').toArray ++ ('A' to 'Z').toArray
                                                   ^
```

Moreover, the following seems to work:

```
scala> ('0' to '9').toArray
res1: Array[Char] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> ('A' to 'Z').toArray
res2: Array[Char] = Array(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z)

scala> res1 ++ res2
res3: Array[Char] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z)
```

Another interesting bit I found:

```
scala> (('0' to '9').toArray) ++ (('A' to 'Z').toArray[Char])
res4: Array[Char] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z)
```

I cannot really explain this - am I missing something?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the real question, by why the premature toArray on both ranges?  Wouldn't `(('0' to '9') ++ ('A' to 'Z')).toArray` prevent this problem?

Comment: I think it is connected to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675419/in-scala-why-do-i-get-this-polymorphic-expression-cannot-be-instantiated-to-ex and type inference

Comment: @whaley I was just playing around with Arrays and came across that finding which I couldn't explain. I know how to get the final result, but I can't really explain why `('0' to '9').toArray ++ ('A' to 'Z').toArray` does not work.
@DavidMichaelGang Yeah, it looks like the same error, but I can't really understand how does that explanation applies here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `++` Method is defined in [`ArrayOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.x/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps@++[B](that:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]):Array[B]):

```
def ++[B](that: GenTraversableOnce[B]): Array[B]
```

> Returns a new mutable indexed sequence containing the elements from
>   the left hand operand followed by the elements from the right hand
>   operand. **The element type of the mutable indexed sequence is the
>   most specific superclass encompassing the element types of the two
>   operands.**

The type of the Array in which the results are stored is inferred.

```
('0' to '9').toArray ++ ('A' to 'Z').toArray
```

`('0' to '9').toArray` works great, and we get back an `Array[Char]`.

```
8: materializing requested scala.reflect.type.ClassTag[Char] using `package`
.this.materializeClassTag[Char]...
```

According to the method definition we accept `GenTraversableOnce[B]`. In our case, we accept `GenTraversableOnce[Char]`.

If we re run scala with the `-Ytyper-debug` option, we can see type inference in action.

```
//it tries to find the type of arg0
typing '0'.to('1').toArray.$plus$plus('A'.to('B').toArray): pt = ?: undetparams=, implicitsEnabled=true, enrichmentEnabled=true, mode=EXPRmode, silent=false, context.owner=value res1
    typing '0'.to('1').toArray.$plus$plus: pt = ?: undetparams=, implicitsEnabled=true, enrichmentEnabled=true, mode=EXPRmode BYVALmode POLYmode FUNmode, silent=true, context.owner=value res1
        typing '0'.to('1').toArray: pt = ?: undetparams=, implicitsEnabled=true, enrichmentEnabled=true, mode=EXPRmode POLYmode QUALmode, silent=true, context.owner=value res1
            typing '0'.to('1'): pt = ?: undetparams=, implicitsEnabled=true, enrichmentEnabled=true, mode=EXPRmode POLYmode QUALmode, silent=true, context.owner=value res1
                typing '0'.to: pt = ?: undetparams=, implicitsEnabled=true, enrichmentEnabled=true, mode=EXPRmode BYVALmode POLYmode FUNmode, silent=true, context.owner=value res1
                    typing '0': pt = ?: undetparams=, implicitsEnabled=true, enrichmentEnabled=true, mode=EXPRmode POLYmode QUALmode, silent=true, context.owner=value res1
                    typed '0': Char('0')
                    adapted '0': Char to ?,
//It succeeds.
//Now it infers a scala type 
    infer implicit view {
  tree         '0'
  pt           Char('0') => ?{def to: ?}

  }
               new ImplicitSearch(floatWrapper) {...}
               ...
                new ImplicitSearch(charWrapper) {...}

   } 

 //The interesting bit...
     typedImplicit1 charWrapper, pt=Char('0') => ?{def to: ?}, from implicit charWrapper:(c: Char)scala.runtime.RichChar   
     Implicit search yielded: SearchResult(scala.this.Predef.charWrapper, )
            typed scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('0').to('1'): scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[Char]
            adapted scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('0').to('1'): scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[Char] to ?,
        typed scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('0').to('1').toArray: [B >: Char](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[B])Array[B]

 //repeat the process 
 Infer implicit {
 tree         scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('0').to('1').toArray[Char]
  pt           scala.reflect.ClassTag[Char]
  undetparams
 }
```

The inference process repeats, and the type is further inferred from the method call on that type, which is `++`. The type of `('0' to '1').toArray ++` is finally resolved to be `ArrayOps`.

```
 Implicit search yielded: SearchResult(scala.this.Predef.charArrayOps, )

 adapted this.charArrayOps(charWrapper('0').to('1').toArray[Char](ClassTag.Char)).++: [B >: Char, That](that: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Array[Char],B,That])That to ?, undetparams=type B, type That
```

Scala then types our second arg...

```
 typed scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('A').to('B'): scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[Char]
        adapted scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('A').to('B'): scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[Char] to ?,
    typed scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('A').to('B').toArray: [B >: Char](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[B])Array[B]
```

Finally, we see if our `Array[B]` has the `GenTraversableOnce` trait.

```
 infer implicit view {
 tree         <empty>
  pt           Array[?B] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
  undetparams
}
```

Of course, it does not and we get :

```
typing private[this] val res1: <error> = '0'.to('1').toArray.$plus$plus('A'.to('B').toArray): pt = ?: undetparams=, implicitsEnabled=true, enrichmentEnabled=true, mode=EXPRmode BYVALmode, silent=false, context.owner=object $iw
                typed private[this] val res1: <error> = scala.this.Predef.charArrayOps(scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('0').to('1').toArray[Char](ClassTag.Char)).++[B, That]('A'.to('B').toArray): <notype>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124177/2823715 for information about why this is the case.

The solution is to use [`++`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.x/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps@++:[B>:A,That](that:Traversable[B])(implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]):That):

```
def ++:[B >: T, That](that: collection.Traversable[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Array[T], B, That]): That
```

> It differs from ++ in that the right operand determines the type of
>   the resulting collection rather than the left one. Mnemonic: the COLon
>   is on the side of the new COLlection type.

It also makes an `ArrayOps` from `Arrays`, so that's what you need.

This is confirmed by our typing debug output:

```
typing {
  <synthetic> val x$1 = '0'.to('1').toArray;
  'A'.to('B').toArray.$plus$plus$colon(x$1)
}:
...
typed scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('0').to('1').toArray: [B >: Char](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[B])Array[B]
...
typing scala.this.Predef.charArrayOps(scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('A').to('B').toArray(ClassTag.Char())).++:(scala.this.Predef.wrapCharArray(x$1), scala.this.Array.canBuildFrom(ClassTag.Char())): pt = Array[Char]: undetparams=, implicitsEnabled=false, enrichmentEnabled=false, mode=EXPRmode BYVALmode, silent=false, context.owner=value res2
...
<synthetic> val x$1: Array[Char] = new runtime.RichChar(scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('0')).to(scala.Char.box('1')).toArray(ClassTag.Char()).$asInstanceOf[Array[Char]]();
  scala.this.Predef.charArrayOps(new runtime.RichChar(scala.this.Predef.charWrapper('A')).to(scala.Char.box('B')).toArray(ClassTag.Char()).$asInstanceOf[Array[Char]]()).++:(scala.this.Predef.wrapCharArray(x$1), scala.this.Array.canBuildFrom(ClassTag.Char())).$asInstanceOf[Array[Char]]()
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems related to: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2394

Perhaps it is just a limitation/unfixable bug related to `Array`s. You can add a type parameter:

```
('0' to '9').toArray ++ ('A' to 'Z').toArray[Char]
```

to get it to work, whereas you don't need the type parameter with:

```
('0' to '9').toList ++ ('A' to 'Z').toList
```