# scala List .toArray failing for no apparent reason

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to make a Build.scala file in Play 2.4. For the Checkstyle part, I looked at how it was implemented and found this:

https://github.com/ymasory/sbt-example-qa/blob/master/project/build.scala

But I'm getting an error that says:

> polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
>
> found: [B >: String}Array[B]]
>
> required: String
>
> PmdMain(args.toArray)

I had a look at the answers here: [In Scala, why do I get this "polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675419/in-scala-why-do-i-get-this-polymorphic-expression-cannot-be-instantiated-to-ex)

But that doesn't actually help me. All the points in the `List` are of type `String`, so I don't see how this error came about.

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Play 2.4 uses sbt 0.13.8, 2.2 uses 0.13.0 far as I know. I don't really follow SBT or Scala, so I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: What's your problem? What do you have already and what are you aiming at?

Comment: I'm trying to build an array of strings to pass to the CheckStyle constructor, as you would on the command line. It is as the code shown in the link.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are calling is probably a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).  In other words, it expects a variable number of arguments.  These parameters are known as *repeated parameters* in Scala, and are often referred to as *varags*.    For example, you can call:

```
PmdMain(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Notice how this is different from `PmdMain(List(arg1, arg2, arg3))` – the former has multiple arguments of type `String`, and the latter has a single argument of type `List[String]`.  The error you are hitting indicates that the first argument in the list is expected to be a `String`, but you provided an `Array[String]`.

If you want to call the method with an instantiated list of arguments, you have to use the special *sequence argument* notation:

```
PmdMain(args: _*)
```

You can read more about repeated parameters and sequence arguments [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters) in the spec.

If you want to play around with this in the REPL, you can recreate the error quite simply:

```
def foo(args: String*) = ??? //The * indicates that args is variadic
foo("bar", "baz") //OK
foo(List("foo", "baz")) //Bad
foo(List("foo", "baz"):_*) //OK
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have no control over the PmdMain function at all. There are tons of examples out there that use this exact line and only from trying it on Play 2.4 instead of Play 2.2, did I find this to be a problem for me. I don't know why this is happening.