# Using implicit to convert string to ZonedDateTime

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have `ZonedDateTime` as a `String`.

I want to be able to convert the string to a `ZonedDateTime` using an implicit conversion.

Here's my conversion:

```
 implicit def string2ZonedDatetime(s: String): ZonedDateTime = {
    ZonedDateTime.parse(s)
  }
```

Here's my usage:

```
val createdAt: ZonedDateTime = "2018-09-28T18:38:39+00:00"
```

But when I execute this I get:

`polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type`.

I have a feeling that this has to do with some sort of implicit evidence? Something like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675419/in-scala-why-do-i-get-this-polymorphic-expression-cannot-be-instantiated-to-ex).

But I don't understand how it applies to this problem.

Comment: I am able to execute it successfully.

Comment: i don't think it's connected somehow with conversions at all. could you provide a bit more code? maybe you pass the values somewhere further in code, maybe to array or smth else?

Comment: Automagic implicit conversions are not recommended for a readable code

Comment: @cchantep What do you mean by that?

Comment: That implicit conversions like this can make your code hard to follow. For my personal experience (and I can imagine also that of @cchantep) I can strongly suggest just writing `ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-09-28T18:38:39+00:00")`. The few extra characters will make reading the code (and eventually debugging it) much more simple than relying on an implicit conversion that has to rely on implicit scoping rules.

Comment: @stefanobaghino So what is the correct use case for an implicit conversion?

Comment: I would simply not use them. As you can read in the documentation, using them actually causes the compiler to issue a warning. https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to import implicitConversions in order to convert it

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def string2ZonedDatetime(s: String): ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(s)

val createdAt: ZonedDateTime = "2018-09-28T18:38:39+00:00"
val nowTime: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now.toString
println(createdAt, nowTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `ZonedDateTime` type inference worked.